# Does entropy increase in an isolated quantum system undergouing unitary evolution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, wavefunction, entropy

Does the second law of thermodynamics still work without wavefunction collapse?

I received these contradicting answers on Quora:

https://qr.ae/TWvoOC

https://qr.ae/TWvoO4

Comment: You will have to be more precise, the question you wrote in the post is different than the one in the title. What is usually decribed by "wave function collapse" is the result of a measurement, i.e. the system is not isolated, but interacts with the measuring device.

Answer (score 1):

The strict answer to the question in the title is: no, isolated systems evolving unitarily do not increase their entropy (if they are isolated, where would the information go?). The subtleties around this issue have to do with the question of "what is entropy anyway". Entropy is always defined by postulating some ignorance about the complete knowledge of the state of the system. In the statistical mechanics formalism the ignorance is (roughly) about the microscopic degrees of freedom. In quantum mechanics it is common to associate ignorance with inaccessible environment. Entropy appears when you discard ("trace out") the information about the state that you are ignorant about. Wave function collapse is the result of discarding all information except for one observable (i.e. position). How the second law of thermodynamics works in quantum mechanics is an area of active research and there is much more to say here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please comment on the first answer I received? Is it wrong?

Comment: @Anixx Yes. He refers to the spread of position eigenvalues of a free particle but that is not entropy. The quantum state of a free particle does not loose information and there is no reason to prefer position eigenvalues over momentum eigenvalues which do not spread at all.